# Is God accountable for all things - good AND bad?

Tags: nature-of-god

Can I build the house without the lord's grace? can I ask him simply not to intervene with my house? I can do a fine work on my own
a lousy labourer building an amazing house - yes, that's the lord grace.
but a skilled labourer with years of practice - god has nothing to do with it, unless he maliciously decides to destroy the labourer's work

If a skilled labourer is being thankful to god for the opportunities he gave him to acquire his skill - should the unemployed labourer complain to god for treating him unfairly and not giving him opportunity?

**If god is responsible for all the good things that happen in our life - is he also accountable for all the bad things?**

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Also, since when is God accountable to anyone, least of all you and me? Doesn't accountability work the other way around? We, the creatures, are accountable to God, not vice versa. Now if you're asking the eternal question of why God ALLOWS both good and bad things to happen, well, that's a different matter and a different question. Don

Comment: This question might belong to Philosophy SE.

Comment: @Caleb should I delete the answer?

Comment: There's are many discussions around this.  The general statements are that in the OT, God allows good and bad things to happen.  In the NT, all bad things are attributed to Satan.  I'm not sure we can answer this question here w/o being opinion based.

Comment: [Two related questions](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11250/why-does-god-often-permit-his-children-to-suffer-in-this-world-more-than-the-wic?rq=1) on [Christians and suffering](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9924/are-christians-supposed-to-suffer)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast - the question was specifically for Christian god (is there another?), so I don't see any fault in asking it here.

Comment: Oded, different Christians come to different conclusions on how to understand God's responsibility, if any, for sin and pain.  If you asked for a particular denomination's view, like Catholicism or Methodism, that would be more answerable here.

Comment: To add another story told by a rabbi: A man was asked to build a house for a rich man,when he had done the job.The rich man gave him the key to the house. Then the worker said to the rich man: If I knew I was building my own house,I would have build it much better!(The point is:we are building our own life,the DNA for the eternal life)

Comment: @Eagel, it's a funny story,
very true according to freakonimics (see chapter about real-estate agents' houses being sold at 10% more).
but it has nothing to do with the question of god's accountability for bad things along with the good.

Comment: @Nathaniel, can you please elaborate?
let's take a sample case - a righteous man turned blind.
how would the different denominations excuse god  from being accountable for this man's mistreatment? (or wouldn't they?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer what seems to be the core of your question.

> If a skilled labourer is being thankful to god for the opportunities he gave > him to acquire his skill - should the unemployed labourer complain to god for
>   treating him unfairly and not giving him opportunity?

A consistent theme in Christian thought is to always be thankful to God, in good times and in bad.

From the point of view of one Christian denomination, Catholic, misfortune and suffering are opportunities to get closer to God, and to let God lead us to a productive path in accord with His will.  In the case you cite, the response recommended is to be thankful to God for providing another opportunity.  The labourer is unemployed, so he embarks on a journey to find employment.  The journey itself will reveal a variety of opportunities and graces **if the Labourer trusts God** and goes forth.   (If all he does is sit around and complain that God didn't find him a job, how thankful is that?)

There's a longer discussion [here](http://www.catholicnewsagency.com/resources/sacraments/anointing-of-the-sick/st-paul-explains-the-meaning-of-suffering/) based upon St Paul's letters and their treatment of suffering as a gift from God.  A few points.

> Pope John Paul II explains why St. Paul writes so much on suffering:
>   “The Apostle shares his own discovery and rejoices in it because of all those whom it can help – just as it helped him – to understand the salvific meaning of suffering” (*Salvifici Doloris*, 1).

From Scripture:

> **Philippians 3:8-11** - Indeed I count everything as loss because of the surpassing worth of knowing Christ Jesus my Lord. For his sake I have suffered the loss of all things, and count them as refuse, in order that I may gain Christ and be found in him, not having a righteousness of my own, based on law, but that which is through faith in Christ, the righteousness from God depends that I may know him and the power of his resurrection, and may share his suffering, becoming like him in his death, that if possible I may attain the resurrection from the dead on faith;
>   **2 Corinthians 12:7-10** - And to keep me from being too elated by the abundance of revelations, a thorn was given me in the flesh, a messenger of Satan, to harass me, to keep me from being too elated. Three times I besought the Lord about this, that it should leave me; but he said to me, ‘My grace is sufficient for you, for my power is made perfect in weakness.’ For the sake of Christ, then, I am content with weaknesses, insults, hardships, persecutions, and calamities; for when I am weak then I am strong”