# Who rejects prosperity theology?

Tags: prosperity-gospel

Which denominations more or less explicitly reject [prosperity theology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosperity_theology)?

As far as I understand, most Charismatics, and probably Pentecostals believe in prosperity theology. Right?

But it is rejected by Baptists, right? Or are there Baptists which believe in this doctrine?

I am writing a manuscript where I touch the question about reception of prosperity theology by various denominations and want to be sure I don't mis-attribute who agrees with this and who disagrees.

Comment: I once asked a similar question, "In which Christian groups is prosperity theology derogatory?"

Comment: Church of Christ rejects it for sure. Probably most Baptists also.

Answer (score 5):

Prosperity Theology (aka "Health and Wealth Gospel") is primarily a perjorative term. Even many who in actuality are subscribing to a "Gospel" characterized by God finanicially and healthfully "blessing" people witha  strict moral code, they would be loathe to use the term.

Indeed, other than some Pentecostals and Charismatics, the general tenets of a Prosperity Theology would definitely have ben [rejected by almost all of the Patristic Church Fathers](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/9924/1039), and the promulgation would have been considered a [pre-Chalcedonian heresy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/5821/1039) which would be rejected by pretty much everybody.

This charge is specifically is why Evangelicals like [John Piper](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/pastor-rick-henderson/osteen-meyer-prosperity-gospel_b_3790384.html) would [call out popular preachers like Joel Osteen](http://www.desiringgod.org/interviews/is-it-ever-appropriate-to-call-out-prosperity-gospel-teachers-by-name) or why [Pope Francis would distance himself from the same](http://www.rawstory.com/rs/2013/12/pope-francis-trashes-the-prosperity-gospel-pompous-christians-are-ugly-pagans/). Evangelicals like [Brian Zhand](https://kindle.amazon.com/work/farewell-mars-evangelical-pastors-biblical-ebook/B00I660TIS/B00I65455C) and liverals like [Brian McLaren](http://www.brianmclaren.net/archives/imported/reflections-on-amahoroafrica-may.html) are in agreement that it is inconsistent with the call of Jesus.