# How how can God be loving if he lets tragedies happen to his children?

Tags: love, death

My wife, whose family is devout to the faith recently lost her father to sudden brain cancer and if that wasn't enough, several unfortunate circumstances arose due to the lack of financial means for the rest of her family. I'm trying to find something in the Bible that can not only assuage her anger at God, but explain how He can be loving when he allows terrible tragedies to occur to his children. I know that tragedy stems from sin, but God still has power to stop it. This is just really shaking both of our faith.

Comment: Hi! This site really isn't meant to address pastoral questions like the one you have; we're attempting to be a more academic-oriented site. It's not a good idea to trust your own suffering to a bunch of random Internet folks; talk to a Christian leader you can trust. For more academic answers to related questions, do a site search for *theodicy*.

Comment: I'm really looking more for places in the Bible that can address this from an intellectual point of view, not people's opinions. Feel free to close this question if you don't think it's appropriate.

Comment: [This question and its answers](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9924/are-christians-supposed-to-suffer/9925#9925) may be of help to you.

Comment: You could also edit your question to say be "What scriptures do people of XYZ denomination/branch refer to in response to the suffering of Christians?"  The problem has been addressed by many people, Catholic, Protestant, Orthodox, and others, and by phrasing the question this way, with mention of your own background, you may get more helpful answers.

Comment: I am very sorry that you've experienced so much tragedy. In addition to what the other commentators have stated, you could turn to the books of Job and Ecclesiastes. Mind you, these books don't necessarily give a straight answer to these problems; but you may find the subjects resonate with what you're going through and there may be some gem in those books that helps you.

Comment: I'd like to remind all users that there a site policy against giving advice on the main site, even in comments. You may go to chat if you like, however. Ref: [But can't I just say one thing?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1588)